# Why my nested plural ICU message does not work in react-intl FormattedMessage?

Tags: reactjs, localization, translation, icu, react-intl

I'm using react-intl and its `<FormattedMessage />` tag.

I want to have a structured message that will pick the correct plural variant based on provided values to allow translators to work with rules of their language, i.e., if they have a different variant for "one", "two", "many", items, etc. I did not want to have it hardcoded inside of the application business logic via `switch` statements that would use just English rules for "zero", "one", and "other".

`<FormattedMessage id="myMessage" values={{applesCount: 4, orangesCount: 0, pearsCount: 1}} />`
should produce `I have some apples and some pears` from the following source.

For some reasons, it returns `I have some apples, some pears, and some oranges`

```
{applesCount, plural, 
    zero {{pearsCount, plural, 
        zero {{orangesCount, plural, 
            zero {I have no fruit}
            other {I have some oranges}
        }}
        other {{orangesCount, plural, 
            zero {I have some pears}
            other {I have some pears and some oranges}
        }}
    }}
    other {{pearsCount, plural, 
        zero {{orangesCount, plural, 
            zero {I have some apples}
            other {I have some apples and some oranges}
        }}
        other {{orangesCount, plural, 
            zero {I have some apples and some pears}
            other {I have some apples, some pears, and some oranges}
        }}
    }}
}
```

I tested it via https://format-message.github.io/icu-message-format-for-translators/editor.html

Also, I have this codesandbox where you can tinker with it: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-intl-formattedmessage-using-plural-x8ki5

For reference, I checked http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/messages and https://formatjs.io/guides/message-syntax/ and would expect that my message structure is supported.

Can you help me detect what is wrong or how should I change it to get it working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is:

> English as a language doesn't have *grammar specialized specifically for zero number of items*.

It is mainly singular or plural (on in some rare residual cases [dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number#Dual)).

The syntax which you are using is specifically for those languages where grammar is specialized specifically for zero number of items. (Examples are Arabic and Latvian)

Read Here: https://formatjs.io/guides/message-syntax/#plural-format.
Also, this article on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number) explains the same

So, the approach won't work for English. Instead you need to use `=0` (=value syntax) for matching quantity to zero for the solution to work.

```
{applesCount, plural, 
    =0 {{pearsCount, plural, 
        =0 {{orangesCount, plural, 
            =0 {I have no fruit}
            other {I have some oranges}
        }}
        other {{orangesCount, plural, 
            =0 {I have some pears}
            other {I have some pears and some oranges}
        }}
    }}
    other {{pearsCount, plural, 
        =0 {{orangesCount, plural, 
            =0 {I have some apples}
            other {I have some apples and some oranges}
        }}
        other {{orangesCount, plural, 
            =0 {I have some apples and some pears}
            other {I have some apples, some pears, and some oranges}
        }}
    }}
}
```

Similarly, for 1 number, `one` won't work for English. You have to use `=value` syntax (`=1`).
Tried this on [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-intl-formattedmessage-using-plural-b6ecr) and works fine.

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts.

Comment: This is a great answer that helped me a lot. I did not realize that "zero" and "=0" are not equivalents. Also, I did not expect that these keywords are matched against the localization name (language ISO code).